# How to check SonarQube code coverage in Eclipse for a specific test class, Maven and Gradel?

Tags: eclipse, junit, sonarqube

Is there any way to check SonarQube code coverage in Eclipse for a specific test class, Maven and Gradel? In a project many Test classes are there so sonar is giving result of all the test cases, so is there any way to check the code coverage for the test class I have written.

Comment: [Eclipse has built-in code coverage](https://www.eclemma.org/).

Answer (score 1):

As @howlger mentions, instead of doing "Run As" on the unit test class, you can do "Coverage As".  After the test is complete, it will set the background color of lines in your "code under test" to show which lines are fully covered (green), not covered (red), or partially covered (yellow).

Also note that you will also get coverage statistics in the "Coverage" view after the test is complete.  Note that the algorithm that SonarQube uses to compute "Coverage" usually won't give you the same numbers you get from running unit tests from Eclipse or from the mvn command line. SonarQube uses a "weighted average" of line and condition coverage, so the numbers will be close, but not exactly the same.